# How can I set $PS1 with Dockerfile?

Tags: bash, docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

How can I set PS1 environment variable (bash prompt) in Dockerfile?
I attempted `ENV PS1 "\h:\W \u$ "`
But this command does not change prompt.
I don't know why above `ENV` does not set PS1 prompt.
How can I do it?

Comment: Stick a `.bashrc`, etc. file in the container? Is the normal shell startup setting `PS1` directly? That would override anything from the environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is happening here is that PS1 is being redefined by the file `~/.bashrc` that is in your image and automatically sourced on start up of your container (it could be on another file - I am not sure if PS1 always get defined in ~/.bashrc on all linux distros).

Assuming it is defined in `~/.bashrc`, then you could write in your Dockerfile a `RUN` command that could look like:

```
RUN echo PS1=\"\\h:\\W \\u$ \" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Et voila!

Comment: If you are looking for a colored one: `RUN echo "PS1='\${debian_chroot:+(\$debian_chroot)}\\[\033[01;32m\\]\\u@\\H\[\\033[00m\\]:\\[\\033[01;34m\\]\\w\\[\\033[00m\\]\\$ '" >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: what if there's no home directory and no .bashrc file?

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional See here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48872/218427

Answer (score 1):

Simple `ENV PS1=...` does not work because PS1 gets redefined later in `.bashrc` file. Here is a simple solution without the need to escape your PS1 string:

```
ENV PS1A="[\d \[\e[33m\]\t\[\e[m\]] \[\e[31m\]\u\[\e[m\]@\[\e[31m\]\h\[\e[m\] \[\e[36m\]\w\[\e[m\]\n $ "

RUN echo 'PS1=$PS1A' >> ~/.bashrc
```